# How to use Plivo's machine detection when calling from a browser using Browser SDK?

Tags: javascript, plivo

I found this document that describes how to use the Machine Detection feature:

https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/machine-detection/

but from what I understand it's for calls made using the Call API.

What about the JavaScript (Browser) SDK? I haven't found how to do it from the browser. There is no parameters related to machine detection in the documentation for `<Dial>`.

I'm using the Browser SDK to make outbound calls. When Plivo calls my Answer URL I provide an XML with a `<Dial`> inside to make the actual call. I would like to detect if this call is answered by a machine.

Is it possible? Does somebody have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

You could use the ConfirmKey and ConfirmSound in the Dial XML to detect if the call was answered by a human or a machine. The ConfirmSound URL can use Speak or Play verbs. [Here](https://api-reference.plivo.com/latest/net/elements/dial/confirm-to-answer-call) is an example of this.

Please raise a [support ticket](https://support.plivo.com/) with us for further assistance.